# If P(A) + P(B) = 1, does P(A|C) + P(B|C) = 1?

Tags: conditional-probability, conditioning

Just to explain where this is coming from. I was working on question 5(b) from stat 110 on conditional probabilities. I'll put a picture of the question and its solution below

[image]

I worked on question 5(b) myself but got the wrong answer. However, I can't see what was the mistake in my logic. The way I did it can be seen below.

W = event of winning first game,
B = event that opponent is a beginner,
I = event that opponent is an intermediate,
M = event that opponent is a master

[image]

I noticed that P(B|W) + P(I|W) + P(M|W) does not add up to 1. Is that the mistake in my solution or am I doing something else wrongly?
Also, does this mean that in general, P(A|C) + P(B|C) =/ 1 even if P(A) + P(B) = 1?

Thank you everyone. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: No. As a counter example, consider $P(A|C) + P(B|C) = 1$ when $B = \bar{A}$.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule we have:

$$\mathbb{P}(A|C) + \mathbb{P}(B|C) 
= \mathbb{P}(A) \cdot \frac{\mathbb{P}(C|A)}{\mathbb{P}(C)} + \mathbb{P}(B) \cdot \frac{\mathbb{P}(C|B)}{\mathbb{P}(C)}.$$

This is a weighted sum of $\mathbb{P}(A)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)$, and the weights can vary substantially depending on the relationship of $A$ and $B$ to $C$.  The condition $\mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) = 1$ does not imply any particular value for the sum of conditional probabilities at issue.